# Why is my loop stopping at the first argument (char of argv) in C?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, cs50

I can't understand why my code is stopping at the first char of the command-line arguments.
I think the problem is in the loop, I need it to check if the command-line argument is a digit, so the first and second parts aren't important.
Thank you and sorry for the messy, I am new to this.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // checking if there is more than one command-line argument
 
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
       // checking if command-line argument is a number
      for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
      {
          printf("%c\n", argv[1][i]);
          if (isdigit(argv[1][i])) 
          {
              return 0;
          }
          else 
          {
              printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
              return 1;
          }
          
      }
      
      
    }
        

    
}
```

Comment: You're _returning_ from `main`, which ends the program.  Surely that's not what you meant?

Comment: no, it's not, but when I print the `argv[1][i]`, it only prints the first char.

Comment: That's because you `return` in every case of the `if/else`. That means the program terminates every time on the first loop/character. If you don't want it to terminate then change at least one of the `return` statements to something else. What exactly do you want the `isdigit` true case to do?

Comment: Remember `argc == 2` means there is `1` argument for the program. `argv[0]` is always the name of the executable being run...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a `return` in the *valid* case, so you're *only* checking the *first* char of `argv[1]`.

You want to *not* terminate the loop in the valid case, accumulating the value.

Here's some refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// so we don't have to include cs50.h ...
typedef char *string;

int
main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    // checking if there is more than one command-line argument
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // checking if command-line argument is a number
    int keyval = 0;
    for (char *cp = argv[1];  *cp != 0;  ++cp) {
        if (! isdigit(*cp)) {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }

        // accumulate the number as we go along, digit-by-digit
        keyval *= 10;
        keyval += (*cp - '0');
    }

    printf("keyval=%d\n",keyval);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's an alternate way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// so we don't have to include cs50.h ...
typedef char *string;

int
main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    // checking if there is more than one command-line argument
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // checking if command-line argument is a number
    for (char *cp = argv[1];  *cp != 0;  ++cp) {
        if (! isdigit(*cp)) {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // we can use a standard function to get the value
    int keyval = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("keyval=%d\n",keyval);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's another way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// so we don't have to include cs50.h ...
typedef char *string;

int
main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    // checking if there is more than one command-line argument
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // checking if command-line argument is a number
    char *cp;
    int keyval = strtol(argv[1],&cp,10);

    // invalid digit found
    if (*cp != 0) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("keyval=%d\n",keyval);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `strtol` will accept a *negative* value (e.g. `-37`) as valid. So, if negative values are not acceptable, we'd need an additional check [just before the *valid* `printf`]:

```
// negative value found
if (keyval < 0) {
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
}
```